# How can we deploy a django app onn google cloud?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, deployment, app.yaml

I am having trouble deploying a developed django app on google console.
Firstly it renames all the files of the app to some random name. Also when I try to hit the website .appspot.com I get an internal error.

**Have created app.yaml file:**

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python27
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
threadsafe: true
# [END runtime]

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: website/static

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

libraries:

- name: django
  version: 1.11
```

**Also have created appengine_cofig.py file:**

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START vendor]
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
# [END vendor]
```

Thanks for the help in advance....

Comment: Not enough information in your post to really be able to help you much. The one thing that stands out is that your are combining syntax from the flexible environment with the standard environment (`entrypoint` only applies to the flexible environment).

Comment: **From a beginner perspective**... how can I get my django website up and running on the google app engine ???

Answer (score 1):

As a complete beginner, I'll suggest following the google documentation here (https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) step by step taking note that:

1. Django default database is sqlite3, you will have to change it to mysql and it is recommended that you do this at the very beggining of creating your  Django app. I recommend following instructions in this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s16p32pndK0)
2. Your app.yaml file should look as so;

```html
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
  application_readable: True
- url: .*
  script: yourapplication.wsgi.application

# Only pure Python libraries can be vendored
# Python libraries that use C extensions can
# only be included if they are part of the App Engine SDK 
# Using Third Party Libraries: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: 1.2.5
- name: django
  version: "1.11"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
# [END django_app]
 
# Google App Engine limits application deployments to 10,000 uploaded files per
# version. The skip_files section allows us to skip virtual environment files
# to meet this requirement. The first 5 are the default regular expressions to
# skip, while the last one is for all env/ files.
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^env/.*$
```

I am also a beginner and I have just managed to deploy my app to GAE, all the best.

Comment: Thanks for the help i have already deployed my app on GAE

Also have uploaded the project on git https://github.com/abhisheklokare/Website-using-Python-Django-Framework 

Do check it...